# How does the linux kernel time sleeping processes?

Tags: linux, algorithm, process, operating-system, kernel

I'm researching the efficiency of the delta queue in timing sleeping processes (https://wiki.osdev.org/Blocking_Process), and I wanted to know if the Linux kernel uses this method.

I've tried looking at the code on github (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/kernel/time), but I'm very unfamiliar with it, and it's cryptic for me. I've tried doing research online, but nothing about the delta queue comes up.

From the very little I've gathered, it seems like it doesn't use the delta queue, but I'm not sure. Does anybody have a definitive answer?

Comment: Some info: https://elinux.org/Kernel_Timer_Systems

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/hrtimers.txt